# Is it possible to disable Symfony 2 event listener and then enable it back

Tags: symfony, events

I need to disable Gedmo\Timestampable listeners in controller and then enable it back within the same request. Here is how to disable it
https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/issues/1722
but I can't find anything about enabling it back. Is it possible?

Comment: Just curious - did my answer end up working for you?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the same solution provided, there is a corresponding `addEventListener()` function.  You would want to save all of the event listeners somewhere else first (perhaps in the same class).  Something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    private $listeners;

    private function disableTimestampable()
    {
        $evm = $this->em->getEventManager();

        $this->listeners = $evm->getListeners();

        foreach ($evm->getListeners() as $event => $listeners) {
            foreach ($listeners as $hash => $listener) {
                if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener) {
                    $evm->removeEventListener(
                        array('prePersist', 'loadClassMetadata', 'onFlush'),
                        $listener
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private function enableTimestampable()
    {
        $evm = $this->em->getEventManager();

        foreach ($this->listeners as $event => $listeners) {
            foreach ($listeners as $hash => $listener) {
                if ($listener instanceof \Gedmo\Timestampable\TimestampableListener) {
                    $evm->addEventListener(
                        array('prePersist', 'loadClassMetadata', 'onFlush'),
                        $listener
                    );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Are these listeners will available to access with $evm->getListeners() if we remove them?

Comment: Fair point, they won't be.  You'd want to save them somewhere temporarily, like in the class or somewhere else.  I modified my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

<del>Thank you for your answers. I tried equal solution with saving listeners and it didn't work. Also I found that I'm on wrong way with removing listeners. More simple and clean solution is to</del>

Disable timestampable feature for my field and update the value manually in Entity's Service class directly before Entity persisting.